# Multiple WordPress Sites on XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp, bitnami

Ok I know this has been answered a few times but as far as I can tell all answers are now outdated. Bitnami released a new installer. Instead of installing to `xampp\htdocs\<name>` it installs directly as `xampp\apps\wordpress` so I can't see a way of installing a new site.

I had stupidly renamed the folder and all instances of `wordpress` as a directory path to ezc only to find out that it didn't work. Turns out 4,300 files opening all at once isn't good for Notepad++...

For those of you aren't aware of the new file structure, it's as follows

```
xampp/
  anonymous/
  apache/
  apps/
    wordpress/
      conf/
      htdocs/
        wp-admin/
        wp-content/
        wp-includes/
      licenses/
      tmp/
  cgi-bin/
  contrib/
  [...]
```

How can I have multiple instances of WordPress hosted locally with XAMPP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hopped onto the Bitnami community and found out how to create multiple sites.

Just pop the following into the command prompt (make sure you're in the same directory as installer)

```
bitnami-wordpress*.exe --wordpress_instance_name blog1
```

Replace the `*` with your version and `blog1` with the name of your site.

Source: http://community.bitnami.com/t/installing-several-wp-sites-on-localhost/25924